# Onclick on bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Ok I'm new to bootstrap themes and all, so was trying to fire a javascript onclick method on 
the below bootstrap button but couldn't figure out how to do so..

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/marketing-narrow.html#">Send Email</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just like any other click event, you can use jQuery to register an element, set an id to the element and listen to events like so:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
  ...
});
```

You can also use inline javascript in the onclick attribute:

```
<a ... onclick="myFunc();">..</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="fire" href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/marketing-narrow.html#">Send Email</a>

$('#fire').on('click', function (e) {

     //your awesome code here

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'onclick' attribute like this :

```
<a ... href="javascript: onclick();" ...>...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem no solutions fix the problem:

```
$(".anima-area").on('click', function (e) {
            return false; //return true;
});
$(".anima-area").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
});
 $(".anima-area").click(function (r) {
           e.preventDefault();
});
$(".anima-area").click(function () {
           return false; //return true;
});
```

Bootstrap button always maintain th pressed status and block all .click code.
If i remove .click function button comeback to work good.

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2380